# MySQL: adding support for Asian characters to an existing database

Tags: mysql, utf-8, non-latin

I'm looking for a best-practices approach to adding support for Asian character sets to an existing database. We have existing tables that are in the `latin1` charset:

```
show create table books
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `contactEmail` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `description` text,
  `price` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Currently when we enter UTF8 chars for the `description` field, we get back '?' chars for Asian chars on the round-trip. Latin1 chars work just fine.

Can I simply convert this table with something like this?

```
ALTER TABLE books CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

I understand that this won't magically fix data already present in the table. I just want it to work properly for new data going forward.

Do I need to worry about collation? I have no idea how that would work for non-latin characters.

Would it make sense to make `utf8` the default for the database? Are there any caveats to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with how MySQL handles character sets, but I have experience with character sets in general.

> Currently when we enter UTF8 chars for the description field, we get back '?' chars for Asian chars on the round-trip. Latin1 chars work just fine.

Because your table is using `latin1` for encoding, it can only store characters that are present in the latin1 character set. Latin1 is a shorthand for ISO-8859-1, you can [see what characters it has](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1#Codepage_layout) — no Asian characters, which is why they won't store. I'm a little surprised MySQL doesn't error on such input.

> Would it make sense to make utf8 the default for the database? Are there any caveats to that?

UTF-8 would be a good choice if you need to store characters from multiple languages. UTF-8, as a Unicode encoding, will let you store any Unicode character (there are literally thousands of them), from many languages. You could store the string "Dog café θλφ 你好" using UTF-8. UTF-8 is widely used, and is able to encode just about anything — I highly recommend it.

I would peruse the Internet to find literature on converting MySQL tables, to make sure there aren't any gotchas. If this is production data, test on an offline dataset — a development table or a QA table.

Last, you seem to indicate that there are half-stored Asian characters somehow in your DB. I'd figure out what *extactly* is stored: if it's the UTF-8 sequence for the Asian character, but the database thinks it's latin1 (a classic case of [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)), some recovery may be possible. I would worry that the conversion may attempt to transform the UTF-8 code units  as if they were latin1, resulting in very interesting output. Test test test.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're getting back '?' is a good sign, as it would suggest that the characters not present in Latin-1 have been properly converted to the replacement character. Before embarking on a project to convert the data, make sure that everything in there is sane. This is especially important if you have more than one application and programming language writing to the database.

One of the simplest ways to do a rough and ready sanity check is to check the character length against the byte length.

```
SELECT length(foo), char_length(foo) FROM bar
```

The first returned value is the [length of the string in bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length), the second is the [length of the string in characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length). If there are any multi-byte characters in there somehow, these two values will differ.

There are a great many guides to converting available on the internet, and of those I've found [one in particular](http://www.bluebox.net/news/2009/07/mysql_encoding/) to be incredibly useful.